# InternetMessageHeaders not updating EWS

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

i loop through received email messages in a Exchange 2010 mailbox. A transport rule has added a MessageHeader X-RR to the message in the box when it was received. With the Exchange 2010 EWS API i set the value of the header to "none" but the value is not saved to the message.

```
For Each h As InternetMessageHeader In Message.InternetMessageHeaders
 If h.Name = "X-RR" Then
                    h.Value = "OK"
                End If
Next
Message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite)
```

When i look at the internetmessageheaders the X-RR is preset but it doesn't contain the "OK" value

Answer (score 0):

The InternetMessageHeader collection is a Read only representation of the underlying PR_Transport_Headers property see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/hh545614(v=exchg.140). So if you want to modify a Header you need to modify the underlying PR_Transport_headers property.